# How to unset variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried so far.

```
var nxt = 'I am next';

window.onscroll = function(){
    var scr = this.pageYOffset;

    if(scr > 400){
        console.log(nxt);
        delete(nxt); // unset here
        console.log(nxt); // expected undefined or null
    }
}
```

I used delete() expecting to remove the reference value inside the variable. Unluckily, it just remain the same. Can somebody give me a clue on how to achieve this kind of scenario?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MDN explained the `delete` operator in its [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Variable is unable to use `delete` operator to remove it. Assign it with `undefined` instead.

Comment: you can use `delete` to `unset`, but your variable should not declare as `var`

Example:

    window.onscroll = function(){
        scr = this.pageYOffset;
    
        if(scr > 400){
            console.log(nxt);
            delete nxt; // unset here
            console.log(nxt); // expected undefined or null
        }
    }


It will work as expected. or you can set to `undefined` or `null`

    nxt = undefined;

(or) 

    nxt = null;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't undeclare a variable. You can set its value to `undefined`, however:

```
nxt = undefined;
```

---

You *can* remove a property from an object, usually, depending on how it was added to the object. If this code is at global scope, your `nxt` variable is also a property of the global object (which you can reference via `window` on browsers), but properties added that way cannot be removed. So you *could* add it differently by doing this instead of declaring it:

```
window.nxt = 'I am next';
```

and then you could completely remove it with `delete`:

```
delete window.nxt;
```

*(Note that `delete` is not a function, it's an operator; you don't use `()` with it, though doing so is harmless.)*

**However**, global variables are a Bad Thing™, so I would probably suggest wrapping all of this in a scoping function, keeping `nxt` a variable, and setting `nxt` to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a global variable for a plugin but not for the whole dom. It's wrap with (function(){ /* code */ })(); correct me if I am doing it wrong. Thanks man. You're the best!

Comment: @user111111: Ah, perfect then, it's already scoped. Nice one.

Comment: `var e = [1,2,3];e[2] = undefined;console.log(e);` will be `[1, 2, undefined]`

Comment: `delete e[2]` will show you `[1, 2, empty]`

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov - Yes, both true. I'm not sure how they relate to the answer...?

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly set the variable to undefined:

`nxt = undefined;`

Comment: Thanks. You're answer is right but I am going to pick T.J's answer because he explained it well. (+ one)

Comment: `var e = [1,2,3];e[2] = undefined;console.log(e);` will be `[1, 2, undefined]`